# Missing assembly in build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, assemblies

I have a third party library that consists of two assemblies which are referenced in my Core project.
One of the assemblies is static referenced from code in my Core project, the other one is only used in the web.config in the web project. The core project is, in turn, referenced from the Web project.

Problem is that the app crashes when I start the web app because the web.config can't be parsed since the second assembly is missing. I guess the compiler can't understand that the Core project should include the second assembly since its loosely linked through the web.config.

I don't want to add the assemblies to the web project since that would be tight coupling, it isn't the web project that has dependency to the assemblies, it is the core project.

I did this which solves it (in the Core project class that uses the third party assembly):

```
    static MyClass()
    {
        var dummy = typeof(ThirdPartyClass);
        if (dummy == null)
            throw new Exception("Do not remove reference to 'ThirdPartyClass'");
    }
```

Its a bit of a hack, but the nice thing is that it only affects the Core project which is the only project that should have knowledge of this third party lib. The `throw new Exception` is there for other devs so that they understand that they cant remove it, plus it takes care of an unused warning.

My question, is this a good valid solution, or are there better ones?

edit: Made a little helper class

```
public static class Util
{
    public static void EnsureStaticReference<T>()
    {
        var dummy = typeof(T);
        if(dummy == null)
            throw new Exception(string.Format("This code is used to ensure that the compiler will include assembly"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is on Connect. [Status: Closed as Won't Fix](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/652785/visual-studio-does-not-copy-referenced-assemblies-through-the-reference-hierarchy), workaround: a post-build-step.

Comment: If build event means to write copy code with magic strings my above solution must be consider cleaner?

Comment: @Anders your solution checks for existence, postbuildevents only copy them. I think you should use both or add that reference to your project and stop worring about coupling

Comment: No need to use copy with my solution. So, im taking it my solution is best if you do not want to use magic string and copt the thing or do not want to reference it from the host project

Answer (score 0):

probably it fails because the dll isn't in the bin directory. 
try add the ThirdPartyClass.dll to the project and then set it to "copy always".
hope it help